# Why use find_element(By...) instead of find_element_by_

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What's the purpose and upside of using By from selenium.webdriver.common.by instead of instead of the normal find_element_by_... methods? For example:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('some_ID')
```

vs:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'some_ID')
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [documentatio](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#)n `find_element()` seem to be kind of "*private*" method that is used by `find_element_by_...()` methods and also might be used in [Page Object](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html)

So using Page Object pattern is the reason why you might need `find_element()` + `By` instead of `find_element_by_...()`.

For example, you have some variable that contains elements' `id` value

```
link_id = "some_id"
```

and you use it to locate element as

```
my_link = driver.find_element_by_id(link_id)
```

If for some reason `id` attribute was removed from element, you need both to update selector and replace `find_element_by_...()` method in `my_link` as

```
link_class_name = "some_class_name"
my_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name(link_class_name)
```

If you use `By`, then your initial locator might be

```
link_locator = (By.ID, "some_id")
```

and you locate your element as

```
my_link = find_element(*link_locator)
```

In case of changes in `HTML` source you need just to update your `link_locator` as

```
link_locator = (By.CLASS_NAME, "some_class_name")
```

and `my_link` remains exactly the same

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems like By can be used to make tests more flexible and easier to maintain.
I am thoroughly confused by Page Object model and have not been able to wrap my head around the concept yet.

Comment: By.*locator type* only just returns a string. Why not just run `driver.find_element("css selector", "[css='something']"`? It seems like By is mostly useless because we could easily just pass in those strings ourselves.

Comment: Yeah.. All variables in `By()` class are simple strings and you can use `"id"` instead of `By.ID`, `"xpath"` instead of `By.XPATH`. I think it was made just to add little verbosity and also to simplify working in IDE- you can see available options when entering `By.`, for example, in `PyCharm`

Comment: how does one import this "By" ? -> ok got it `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`  should mention that

Answer (score 2):

Like above answer. I get the deprecated message when using `find_element_by_id` etc. So best way should be by using `find_element()`.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these methods are from the RemoteWebDriver class.

```
findElement(By.id()) requires you to created your own By.id instance.
findElementById(String) is a helper function that will generate the By.id
instance for you.
```

It comes down to providing you with the flexibility to choose what you want
to keep track of in your tests/framework.
Do you want to track locators as Strings?
Do you want to track locators as By objects?

Comment: OP is looking for an answer in `Python`. Your explanations are not applicable in this exact case as there are several differences in `Python`+`Selenium` and `Java`+`Selenium`

Answer (score 1):

Also in the new python version, `find_element_by_...()` is removed, so just use `find_element()` + `By`